# Loading more data onEndReached in a react-native FlatList is scrolling to top of the FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, setstate

[Gif file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH4VN.gif)

In the above gif, you can see that when I scroll to the end, after loading extra data and appending it, the scroll gets reset and scrolled to the top.

Here's the code

**State variable declaration**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); //Contains the fetched data
const [isFetching, setFetching] = useState(false); //To indicate status
```

**Fetch data function**

```
const fetchMarketData = async () => {
const marketData = await getCryptoMarketData({ page });
if (marketData.status != 401) {
  setData(
    data.length > 0
      ? marketData.filter((d) => data.forEach((s) => d.ticker != s.ticker)) //Appending new data id the data is not empty
      : marketData //If the data is empty then it's the first fetch.
  ); 
  setFetching(false);
} else {
  setFetching(false);
  Alert.alert(marketData, "Sorry for the inconvenience");
}
```

};

**Use Effect function**

```
useEffect(() => {
setFetching(true);
const data = async () => {
  await fetchMarketData();
};
data();
}, []);
```

**Load more data**

```
 const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setFetching(true);
    setPage(() => page + 1);
    () => fetchMarketData;
  };
```

**Footer indicator**

```
 const renderFooter = () => {
    return isFetching ? (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 10, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#1f1f1f" />
      </View>
    ) : null;
  };
```

**The Flatlist**

```
<BottomSheetFlatList
      ref={scrollRef}
      data={data}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={renderItems} //Render items just displays the data
      maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why is because u REPLACING and not APPENDING state, in other words you replacing data not adding new

Replacing:

```js
setState([{}])
```

Appending:

```js
let nextPageData = [{}]
setState([...state, ...nextPageData])
```

so fix for your case is this ( but i m not sure when FALSE in if happends, cuz normal API doesnt send u old data just always new ... this is maybe bug on your side too )

```js
let newData = data.length > 0 ? marketData.filter((d) => data.forEach((s) => d.ticker != s.ticker)) : marketData
setData([...data, ...newData]);
```